# Django: Not null constraint even though null=True?

Tags: django

I'm getting this when I submit my Model form:

`null value in column "bio_1" violates not-null constraint`

event though the value is set correctly in my models:

`bio_1 = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)`

I've run my migrations, and the field is not included anywhere in the form's view.

What else could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you look in the database to see whether the constraint exists?

Comment: Hrm. Not null is set to "Yes" I guess my migrations somehow skipped a step. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look in the database to see whether the constraint exists?

Maybe you didn't really run the migrations.

Comment: They've been run, and if I try to run them again it says `No migrations to apply.` This problem has been replicated on multiple columns, so I'm manually changing each of them to conform to the models.

Comment: Migrations are one of the things i dislike about django.